# Recalling a list inside another list Python - TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am trying to call a list of strings inside another list that I am using in a `for` loop.

```
lista_solic = {"name1" : "Full Name 1",
               "name2" : "Full Name 2",
               "name3" : "Full Name 3" } 
list_bcsulc = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
list_sol = [lista_solic[list_bcsulc]]
```

I separated these into two lists because I will use them separately later in the program. Once the program runs, I get the following error:

```
    list_sol = [lista_solic[list_bcsulc]]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

When I try writing it as a tuple, it also givens me an error

```
lista_solic = {"name1" : "Full Name 1",
               "name2" : "Full Name 2",
               "name3" : "Full Name 3" } 
list_bcsulc = ("name1", "name2", "name3")
list_sol = [lista_solic[list_bcsulc]]
```

Error:

```
File "Relatorio_Filtro.py", line 160, in bcsul_contra
    list_sol = [lista_solic[list_bcsulc]]
KeyError: ('name1', 'name2', 'name3,)
```

or

```
    list_sol = [lista_solic[list_bcsulc()]]
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

**Question:**
How can one call a list of strings inside another list to bring values from a dictionary?

`list = dic[list]`

Comment: There is no way to use a list as a key in a dictionary.

Comment: when I try making it as a tuple with parenthresis ** () ** it brings me another erros just listing the entire tuple

Comment: list_sol = [lista_solic[x] for x in list_bcsulc]

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Tuples are allowed to be dictionary keys since they are immutable. See http://ideone.com/UQoey6

Comment: I just edited the question. When as a Tuple, I get those two errors. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Iterate over list_bcsulc. Something like `list_sol = [] for l in list_bcsulc: list_sol.append(lista_solic[l])`

Comment: `list_sol = [lista_solic[name] for name in list_bsulc]` should give you what you want.